# cannot pass spinner value android to php

Tags: php, android

I need to read data from an external database with hundreds of items. so for i am trying to pass spinner selected value to php

android:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.icd);
states = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Diseases);
t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.country_spinner);

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, states);
dataAdapter
        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        value = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        // define the parameter
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("789", value));
        try {
            CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet("789");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['789'])){
$id = $_POST['789']; 
$sql = "SELECT icd_symptoms FROM icd WHERE icd_disease = 'id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
```

how can I pass the data from spinner android to php query so the query will only return the proper items against selected value

Answer (score 0):

Well `CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet("789");` should return the result of you query afterwards you can do whatever you with the result.

Comment: i have edited question and enterd php code but no output for spinner value

Comment: i have done the same with button click but its giving some problem in spinner value..